# Using laser_filter node

Tags: ros, laser-filters, laser-pipeline, pointcloud

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello, I'm trying to get the "scan_to_cloud_filter_chain", located in the laser_filter node, to execute but it keeps giving me the error :

**[ WARN] [1317231063.120226126]: Use of default '~target_frame' parameter in scan_to_cloud_filter_chain has been deprecated.  Default currently set to 'base_link' please set explicitly as appropriate.**

When I get this error nothing appears in Rviz.

I am using the laser scan data provided by ROS. This data is located on the same page as the Laser Filtering tutorial.

This is the tutorial I am following [Laser filtering using the filtering nodes](http://www.ros.org/wiki/laser_filters/Tutorials/Laser%20filtering%20using%20the%20filter%20nodes)

Here is the source code take directly from the laser_filter node :

```
#include <ros/ros.h>
#include <sensor_msgs/PointCloud.h>
#include <sensor_msgs/LaserScan.h>

#include <float.h>

// Laser projection
#include <laser_geometry/laser_geometry.h>

// TF
#include <tf/transform_listener.h>
#include "tf/message_filter.h"
#include "message_filters/subscriber.h"

//Filters
#include "filters/filter_chain.h"

class ScanToCloudFilterChain
{
public:

  // ROS related
  laser_geometry::LaserProjection projector_; // Used to project laser scans

  double laser_max_range_;           // Used in laser scan projection
  int window_;

  bool high_fidelity_;                    // High fidelity (interpolating time across scan)
  std::string target_frame_;                   // Target frame for high fidelity result
  std::string scan_topic_, cloud_topic_;

  ros::NodeHandle nh;
  ros::NodeHandle private_nh;

  // TF
  tf::TransformListener tf_;

  message_filters::Subscriber<sensor_msgs::LaserScan> sub_;
  tf::MessageFilter<sensor_msgs::LaserScan> filter_;

  double tf_tolerance_;
  filters::FilterChain<sensor_msgs::PointCloud> cloud_filter_chain_;
  filters::FilterChain<sensor_msgs::LaserScan> scan_filter_chain_;
  ros::Publisher cloud_pub_;

  // Timer for displaying deprecation warnings
  ros::Timer deprecation_timer_;
  bool  using_scan_topic_deprecated_;
  bool  using_cloud_topic_deprecated_;
  bool  using_default_target_frame_deprecated_;
  bool  using_laser_max_range_deprecated_;
  bool  using_filter_window_deprecated_;
  bool  using_scan_filters_deprecated_;
  bool  using_cloud_filters_deprecated_;
  bool  using_scan_filters_wrong_deprecated_;
  bool  using_cloud_filters_wrong_deprecated_;

  ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
  ScanToCloudFilterChain () : laser_max_range_ (DBL_MAX), private_nh("~"), filter_(tf_, "", 50),
                   cloud_filter_chain_("sensor_msgs::PointCloud"), scan_filter_chain_("sensor_msgs::LaserScan")
  {
    private_nh.param("high_fidelity", high_fidelity_, false);
    private_nh.param("notifier_tolerance", tf_tolerance_, 0.03);
    private_nh.param("target_frame", target_frame_, std::string ("base_link"));

// DEPRECATED with default value
    using_default_target_frame_deprecated_ = !private_nh.hasParam("target_frame");

// DEPRECATED
    using_scan_topic_deprecated_ = private_nh.hasParam("scan_topic");
    using_cloud_topic_deprecated_ = private_nh.hasParam("cloud_topic");
    using_laser_max_range_deprecated_ = private_nh.hasParam("laser_max_range");
    using_filter_window_deprecated_ = private_nh.hasParam("filter_window");
    using_cloud_filters_deprecated_ = private_nh.hasParam("cloud_filters/filter_chain");
    using_scan_filters_deprecated_ = private_nh.hasParam("scan_filters/filter_chain");
    using_cloud_filters_wrong_deprecated_ = private_nh.hasParam("cloud_filters/cloud_filter_chain");
    using_scan_filters_wrong_deprecated_ = private_nh.hasParam("scan_filters/scan_filter_chain");


    private_nh.param("filter_window", window_, 2);
    private_nh.param("laser_max_range", laser_max_range_, DBL_MAX);
    private_nh.param("scan_topic", scan_topic_, std::string("tilt_scan"));
    private_nh.param("cloud_topic", cloud_topic_, std::string("tilt_laser_cloud_filtered"));


    filter_.setTargetFrame(target_frame_);
    filter_.registerCallback(boost::bind(&ScanToCloudFilterChain::scanCallback, this, _1));
    filter_.setTolerance(ros::Duration(tf_tolerance_));

    if (using_scan_topic_deprecated_)
      sub_.subscribe(nh, scan_topic_, 50);
    else
      sub_.subscribe(nh, "scan", 50);

    filter_.connectInput(sub_);

    if (using_cloud_topic_deprecated_)
     cloud_pub_ = nh.advertise<sensor_msgs::PointCloud> (cloud_topic_, 10);
    else
      cloud_pub_ = nh.advertise<sensor_msgs::PointCloud> ("cloud_filtered", 10);

    std::string cloud_filter_xml;

    if (using_cloud_filters_deprecated_)
      cloud_filter_chain_.configure("cloud_filters/filter_chain", private_nh);
    else if (using_cloud_filters_wrong_deprecated_)
      cloud_filter_chain_.configure("cloud_filters/cloud_filter_chain", private_nh);
    else
      cloud_filter_chain_.configure("cloud_filter_chain", private_nh);

    if (using_scan_filters_deprecated_)
      scan_filter_chain_.configure("scan_filter/filter_chain", private_nh);
    else if (using_scan_filters_wrong_deprecated_)
      scan_filter_chain_.configure("scan_filters/scan_filter_chain", private_nh);
    else
      scan_filter_chain_.configure("scan_filter_chain", private_nh);

    deprecation_timer_ = nh.createTimer(ros::Duration(5.0), boost::bind(&ScanToCloudFilterChain::deprecation_warn, this, _1));
  }

  // We use a deprecation warning on a timer to avoid warnings getting lost in the noise
  void deprecation_warn(const ros::TimerEvent& e)
  {
    if (using_scan_topic_deprecated_)
      ROS_WARN("Use of '~scan_topic' parameter in scan_to_cloud_filter_chain has been deprecated.");

    if (using_cloud_topic_deprecated_)
      ROS_WARN("Use of '~cloud_topic' parameter in scan_to_cloud_filter_chain has been deprecated.");

    if (using_laser_max_range_deprecated_)
      ROS_WARN("Use of '~laser_max_range' parameter in scan_to_cloud_filter_chain has been deprecated.");

    if (using_filter_window_deprecated_)
      ROS_WARN("Use of '~filter_window' parameter in scan_to_cloud_filter_chain has been deprecated.");

    if (using_default_target_frame_deprecated_)
      ROS_WARN("Use of default '~target_frame' parameter in scan_to_cloud_filter_chain has been deprecated.  Default currently set to 'base_link' please set explicitly as appropriate.");

    if (using_cloud_filters_deprecated_)
      ROS_WARN("Use of '~cloud_filters/filter_chain' parameter in scan_to_cloud_filter_chain has been deprecated.  Replace with '~cloud_filter_chain'");

    if (using_scan_filters_deprecated_)
      ROS_WARN("Use of '~scan_filters/filter_chain' parameter in scan_to_cloud_filter_chain has been deprecated.  Replace with '~scan_filter_chain'");

    if (using_cloud_filters_wrong_deprecated_)
      ROS_WARN("Use of '~cloud_filters/cloud_filter_chain' parameter in scan_to_cloud_filter_chain is incorrect.  Please Replace with '~cloud_filter_chain'");

    if (using_scan_filters_wrong_deprecated_)
      ROS_WARN("Use of '~scan_filters/scan_filter_chain' parameter in scan_to_scan_filter_chain is incorrect.  Please Replace with '~scan_filter_chain'");

  }


  ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
  void
  scanCallback (const sensor_msgs::LaserScan::ConstPtr& scan_msg)
  {
    //    sensor_msgs::LaserScan scan_msg = *scan_in;

    sensor_msgs::LaserScan filtered_scan;
    scan_filter_chain_.update (*scan_msg, filtered_scan);

    // Project laser into point cloud
    sensor_msgs::PointCloud tmp_cloud;
    sensor_msgs::PointCloud scan_cloud;

    //\TODO CLEAN UP HACK 
    // This is a trial at correcting for incident angles.  It makes many assumptions that do not generalise
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < filtered_scan.ranges.size(); i++)
    {
      double angle = filtered_scan.angle_min + i * filtered_scan.angle_increment;
      filtered_scan.ranges[i] = filtered_scan.ranges[i] + 0.03 * exp(-fabs(sin(angle)));

    };

    // Transform into a PointCloud message
      int mask = laser_geometry::channel_option::Intensity |
      laser_geometry::channel_option::Distance |
      laser_geometry::channel_option::Index |
      laser_geometry::channel_option::Timestamp;
  
    if (high_fidelity_)
    {
      try
      {
        projector_.transformLaserScanToPointCloud (target_frame_, filtered_scan, scan_cloud, tf_, mask);
      }
      catch (tf::TransformException &ex)
      {
        ROS_WARN("High fidelity enabled, but TF returned a transform exception to frame %s: %s", target_frame_.c_str (), ex.what ());
        return;
        //projector_.projectLaser (filtered_scan, scan_cloud, laser_max_range_, preservative_, mask);
      }
    }
    else
    {
       projector_.projectLaser (filtered_scan, tmp_cloud, laser_max_range_, mask);
       tf_.transformPointCloud(target_frame_,  tmp_cloud, scan_cloud);
    }
  
    sensor_msgs::PointCloud filtered_cloud;
    cloud_filter_chain_.update (scan_cloud, filtered_cloud);

    cloud_pub_.publish(filtered_cloud);
  }

} ;



int
main (int argc, char** argv)
{
  ros::init (argc, argv, "scan_to_cloud_filter_chain");
  ros::NodeHandle nh;
  ScanToCloudFilterChain f;

  ros::spin();

  return (0);
}
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11349/using-laser_filter-node./) by [tyler258](https://answers.ros.org/users/1092/tyler258/) on ROS Answers with karma: 93 on 2011-09-28

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

What this warning says is that you have not explicitly set the target frame of the filter. While it's currently defaulting to "base_link", you want to explicitly declare that as the default. Try adding this to the launch file under the scan_to_cloud_filter_chain node:

```
<param name="target_frame" value="base_link" />
```

---

Originally posted by [DimitriProsser](https://answers.ros.org/users/635/dimitriprosser/) with karma: 11163 on 2011-09-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1